# Oracle Apex 4.2 -- Is there a method to access one application in different ways?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a login app that is responsible for the login of other five applications. So when the user correctly authenticates in the first login, he can access all the other apps. 
I have achieved this using the same cookie name for the login app and all the other applications.

But only one of this applications must be accessible  *from the outside*
too, and not only from the login page. So it must have his own login page.

**Question:**

Is there a way to make this application accessible in two ways? 
One way coming from the login application and the other way from its own login page?

Or I must have two separate applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, this "login app" is used as a *menu* which enables users to access 5 different applications. Those are, I suppose, Apex applications.

If that's so, make the link (i.e. URL) to the one that has to be accessible "outside" of the login app available to users separately. All of URLs are the same, aren't they? You only change the APP_ID value.

Now, the problem might arise with the way of authentication. How did you do that? If it is user-defined, and "available" only in the login app, then you'll have to make it available to that separate application as well. Otherwise, users won't be able to connect to it. Lucky for you, you can create a new authentication scheme as a copy of existing one.

Though, underlying database objects (such as table that stores usernames and passwords, functions and procedures used to create new users and fetch data about existing ones, password validations etc.) will also have to be accessible to another database user. That can be done by granting appropriate privileges (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on table(s), EXECUTE on stored procedures).

Therefore, no - I don't think that you should maintain two exactly the same copies of that application to make it work.